# Resizing an alternating background image to fit the screen

Tags: javascript, image, background, resize

A little background - I write java, python, c# and hacky shell scripts by trade and have next to no experience with javascript (literally started today). I've been digging around and none of the questions here on stackoverflow have worked so far (or, perhaps I haven't the knack at js yet to make them work).

Anyhow, the story - I'd like a page in which the background alternates between a set of predetermined images that are stored locally (bg01.jpg to bgXX.jpg). I have figured out how to cycle through the images and now I would like these images to actually fit the document background .. rather than just .. doing their own thing.

Here is what I have so far (which works) - (edited 15th Oct)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
body {background-repeat:no-repeat;}
</style>
<body>

<script>

var bgslides=new Array()
bgslides[0]="bg01.jpg"
bgslides[1]="bg02.jpg"
bgslides[2]="bg03.jpg"
bgslides[3]="bg04.jpg"
bgslides[4]="bg05.jpg"


//Specify interval between slide (in miliseconds)
var speed=1000

//preload images
var processed=new Array()
for (i=0;i<bgslides.length;i++){
    processed[i]=new Image()
    processed[i].src=bgslides[i]
}

var inc=-1
function slideback(){
if (inc<bgslides.length-1)
    inc++
else
    inc=0
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url("+bgslides[inc]+")";
}

if (document.all||document.getElementById)
window.onload=new Function('setInterval("slideback()",speed)')


</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried

```
image.width = ..
image.height = ..
```

But I think that the call to

```
document.body.background = image.src
```

Overrides previous changes to image.width .. Not that I have much clue. I have also tried a few different resize functions that I have found about the place and modified, and attempted to alter the css (the  section?) in js and so far ..nada.

Is there anything that I can slot in to this to get it resizing happily?!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of document.body.background line, have you thought about something like

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url("+bgslides[inc]+")";
```

A few notes.
 - The "new Image()" works with  tags, but other than preloading the image, you wouldn't use that for CSS backgrounds.
 - Even though JavaScript doesn't require it, it is strongly recommended to end statements with semicolons.
 - You have a line "processed[i].size = " that is left undefined.
 - You also include the "document.body.background =  processed[inc].src" inside the else statement, when it should be outside the whole if/then.

Comment: Ah I must have missed the size line when copy / paste / editing - good spoting! I've swapped the 'document.body.background =  processed[inc].src' for 'document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url("+bgslides[inc]+")";' - no visible change. Also, it turns out that it does have to be in the else {} section or the code doesn't seem to work at all. Huh. Not that js says why even in the webconsole.

Comment: In your demo code you still have that line inside the else statement so it won't be called most of the time.  Also, "if (document.all||document.getElementById)" returns false, you never set the timeout.  I'm not sure why you're calling that.  And I don't think "Function" should be capitalized.  Or even called.  I don't think you need window.onload either.  You probably just want the setInterval call.

Comment: Hi again, if you are referring to to "document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url("+bgslides[inc]+")";" then as I say, the code doesn't work at all if I put it outside the if else segment. I have no idea why - it just doesn't. I am not sure why it calls that either - I found the code segment somewhere and it was the first block that semi worked after hours of trawling the internet :). I'd be happy to try a different style if you'd care to present it.

Comment: Hi Dan! Sure thing! .. But how to resize the images?